# send arguments to bash script with "#"

Tags: bash

How may one `bash script.sh #hello #world`?
If, for instance, one is attempting to supply hex codes to the script, and wishes to use a `#`, how do you accept that input? Is there a way to override the functionality as a comment?

Comment: Quotes. `'#hello'`, or `'#'hello`, or `\#hello`, or `"#hello"`, etc etc.

Comment: In addition to what Charles Duffy said: If theat user invoking your shell is doing it via an interactive shell, he can also configure it via `shopt -u interactive_comments` and then does not need to quote or escape the `#`.